# How to export favorites from Internet Explorer

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use PS to export favorites from IE11 as a single html file including directory structure.  The intention being to run this for every user on Win7 for importing to Edge in Win10.

I have used get-childitem to find the folders and files but can't figure out how to build the file with the structure in place.  A folder is indicated with tags of `<DL></DL>` so nested folder would look something like `<DL>contents<DL>contents</DL></DL>`.  I can get the name and path of each folder and can use foreach to create each object but can't figure out how to get the correct structure.

```bsh
Get-ChildItem ("$env:userprofile\Favorites") -Directory -Recurse | ForEach {
    $foname=$_.Name
    $fopath=$_.FullName
    if(Test-Path "$fopath\*"){
        $body+="<DT><H3>$foname</H3>`n"
        $body+="<DL><p>`n"
        Get-ChildItem ("$fopath") -File | ForEach {
            $finame = $_.Name.TrimEnd(".url")
            $fiurl = ($_ | Select-String "^URL").Line.Trim("URL=")
            $body+="<DT><A HREF='$fiurl'>$finame</A>`n"
        }
        $body+="</DL><p>`n"
    }
}
```

My code creates the folders and urls required but doesn't nest them correctly.

Comment: I would use `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("Favorites")` to get the real path to the favorites folder. Not everyone has this in the default location of `$env:userprofile\Favorites`

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Theo, I can rely on all of our users having the same location but accept that in general it will be best to use your method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use recursion (create a function which calls itself if there are remaining child items).

```
function Get-Folders($path) {
    Get-ChildItem $path -Directory | % {
        "<DL>$($_.BaseName)"
        if ((Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Directory).Count -gt 0) {
            Get-Folders $_.FullName
        }
        "</DL>"
    }
}

Get-Folders ("$env:userprofile\Favorites")
```

Edit: I noticed I didn't respond exactly to your question (too quick to read).  Here's a more to-the-point version of the code (still built around a recursive function).  It shows the files as well (notice the property .BaseName - that's a handy one to remember).

```
$indent = -4
function Spaces  { return " " * $indent}
function Indent  { $global:indent += 4 }
function Outdent { $global:indent -= 4 }

function Get-Folders($path) {
    Get-ChildItem $path -Directory | % {
        Indent
        "$(Spaces)<DL>"
        Indent
        "$(Spaces)$($_.BaseName)"
        if ((Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Directory).Count -gt 0) {
            Get-Folders $_.FullName
        }

        Indent
        Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File -Filter "*.url" | % {
            "$(Spaces)<DT>($_.BaseName)</DT>"
        }
        Outdent

        Outdent
        "$(Spaces)</DL>"
        Outdent
    }
}

Get-Folders "$env:userprofile\Favorites"
```

Comment: Out of habit, I have used % instead of Foreach-Object.  I know many people don't agree, but I prefer ? for Where and % for Foreach.

Comment: The last thing I had to figure out was the indentation.  I did it in a slightly different way but got the result I wanted, will have a play with your method.  Thanks for your help.